# How Make an Existing Wpf application is Database independent using MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Currently,I have a Wpf application in Visual studio 2010 with Mssqlserver back end.
I need to make this application is database independent, ie it should be working in all database like oracle,access etc.
How is this possible?
Any Possibility with MVC4?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean...Your asking for a way to make your app work on multiple different DB Systems? Can I ask why?

Comment: I Have database in sqlsrver and oracle.Now my application working with sqlserver database, I need my application should be working with all databases without considering back end server .And I have heard about MVC with module for this purpose.How is possible this